# IF/THEN Tableau calculation to catch all past a certain character

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a dataset from SharePoint that users can select multiple options from as an answer that I want to reflect in Tableau. These show as combined selections in a Tableau table deliminated with a ";".

One answer could show up as a single-selection such as:

```
| Classification |
| -------------- |
| SelectionA     |
```

I can change the name of this using a simple IF/THEN for multiple single-selections with

```
IF [Classification] = "SelectionA" THEN "New Name" END
```

My obstacle is separating out the multiple-selections and adding a 'catch all' for the rest.
For example:

```
| Classification                   |
| -------------------------------- | 
| SelectionA;SelectionB;SelectionC | 
| Thing1;Thing2;Thing3, etc        |
```

I would like to have those with multiple-selections to form a new name. I have typed this but am not sure where to proceed since the statement and nested loop below both do not work

```
IF [Classification] = "SelectionA" THEN "New Name" 
ELSEIF [Classification] = "SelectionA;" THEN "New Name+"
ELSEIF [Classfication] = "Thing1" THEN "New Thing"
ELSEIF [Classfication] = "Thing1;" THEN "New Thing+"
END
```

AND

```
IF SPLIT ([Classification], ";",1) = "SelectionA" THEN
    IF SPLIT ([Classification], ";",2) IF NOT ISNULL THEN "New Name+"
    ELSE "New Name"
    END
ELSEIF SPLIT ([Classification], ";",1) = "SelectionA.1" THEN
    IF SPLIT ([Classification], ";",2) IF NOT ISNULL THEN "New Name+"
    ELSE "New Name"
    END
```

With the end result in my head as

```
| Classification                   | Classificaiton(new)
| -------------------------------- | -------------------
| SelectionA                       | New Name
| SelectionA;SelectionB;SelectionC | New Name+
| Thing1                           | New Thing
| Thing1;Thing2;Thing3, etc        | New Thing+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a one-to-many relationship in your data.

I would focus on representing the data in a clear and logical way in the database (or data store) and then worry about the visualization

The standard approach in relational databases is to represent the data with two tables -- where one table has a column (known as a foreign key) that references the other table. The problem is that SharePoint breaks the standard relational database model by cramming multiple values into these cells. Perhaps that makes a few things easier in SharePoint, but it causes no end of problems trying to analyze the data. Thanks Microsoft :-(

You can use Tableau Prep or Python to convert the data to more structured/normalized relational model

For instance, if each mother has many children (and thus each child has a single mother) then you would have one table (say called Woman) and other table (say called Child). Each row in the Woman table represents exactly one woman and each row in the Child table represents exactly one child. Each table would have a single column (say called ID) with a unique ID for each record - called a primary key. The child table also would have a required column called mother_ID (or perhaps woman_ID) which associates each child with its mother. Note with this model, you can have women who have no associated children, but each child has exactly one mother.

Once you do have your data in a more reasonable structure, there are several ways to  choose to display it.